# Finding the change of basis matricies

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Not quite sure what to do for this question.

Let $B_1$= {$\vec{u}_1,\vec{u}_2,\vec{u}_3$} and $C_1$= {$\vec{w}_1,\vec{w}_2,\vec{w}_3$} be two bases for $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that
$\vec{w}_1=\vec{u}_1-\vec{u}_2,$  $\vec{w}_2=\vec{u}_2-\vec{u}_3, $ $\vec{w}_3=\vec{u}_2+\vec{u}_1 $.
Find the change of coordinates matrices $P_{{C_1}\to {B_1}}$ and $P_{{B_1}\to {C_1}}$

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This exercise was perhaps intended to reinforce your understanding of change of basis matrices.  But the little you've written suggests you simply posted the assignment without attempting the problem first.  At a minimum you should add context to this bare problem statement, or risk Readers interpreting the post as a request to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm not sprinking all the little \vec s through this answer.)

Interpreted in the $C_1$ basis, the vector $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ is $w_1$.  To indicate with respect to which basis a vector is written, we subscript it with that basis.  So we could write
$$  \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}_{C_1} = w_1  \text{.}  $$

Notice that
$$  P_{C_1 \rightarrow B_1} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}_{C_1}  $$
gives $1$ times the first column of $P_{C_1 \rightarrow B_1}$ plus zero times the other columns.  We are given that (the same quantity since the $P$ matrix is being multiplied by an alias for the same vector)
$$  P_{C_1 \rightarrow B_1} \cdot w_1 = u_1 - u_2 = \begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix}_{B_1}  \text{.}  $$

So the first column of $P_{C_1 \rightarrow C_2}$ must be $\begin{matrix}1\\-1\\0\end{matrix}$.  Similarly, the second column must be $\begin{matrix}0\\1\\-1\end{matrix}$.  You should be able to find the last column.

To go in the other direction, solve for $u_1$, $u_2$, and $u_3$ in terms of the $w_j$s and then repeat the above analysis using these three solutions to write down the columns of $P_{B_1 \rightarrow C_1}$.

Comment: Hei, I'm not quite sure what you mean by "We are given that (the same quantity since the P matrix is being multiplied by an alias for the same vector)" and the equation below it. don't quite understand how that gives you the first column of the change of basis matrix.

Comment: @MarkusHamre : We are given $P_{C_1 \rightarrow B_1} w_1 = u_1 - u_2$.  Also, $$P_{C_1 \rightarrow B_1} \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}_{C_1} = P_{C_1 \rightarrow B_1} w_1  \text{.}  $$

Comment: Alright I think I understand is the last column $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @MarkusHamre : The column you have written says that $w_3 = u_1 + u_3$, which does not match what you have recited for the problem.

Comment: For $w_2$, we have that $w_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$. Then in the B basis any vector can be written as the linear combination $x_1u_1+x_2u_2+x_3u_3$ so then we have that $u_2-u_3=x_1u_1+x_2u_2+x_3u_3$ finding the values of x that make this true gives $x_1=0,x_2=1,x_3=-1$ giving us the column $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$. Is this the correct way of thinking?

Comment: Yes, I think so.  Do you start to see why I mark all "column list of numbers"s with the basis that turns them into their intended vector?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121019/discussion-between-markus-hamre-and-eric-towers).

Answer (score 1):

Given $\vec{w_1} = \vec{u_1}-\vec{u_2},\:\:\:\vec{w_2} = \vec{u_2}-\vec{u_3},\:\:\: \vec{w_3} = \vec{u_2}+\vec{u_1}$

Every vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be written as a linear combination of the vectors in $C_1$, and also the vectors in $B_1$, and given a linear combination of the vectors in $C_1$, what is the corresponding vector as a linear combination of the vectors in $B_1$? There is a translation of coefficients:

$a_1\vec{w_1}+a_2\vec{w_2}+a_3\vec{w_3}= (a_1+a_3)\vec{u_1}+(-a_1+a_2+a_3)\vec{u_2}+(-a_2)\vec{u_3}$, which implies

$\begin{bmatrix} \vec{w_1}\; \big|\; \vec{w_2}\;\big|\;  \vec{w_3}\: \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \vec{u_1}\; \big|\; \vec{u_2}\;\big|\;  \vec{u_3}\: \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a_1+a_3 \\ -a_1+a_2+a_3 \\ -a_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \vec{u_1}\; \big|\; \vec{u_2}\;\big|\;  \vec{u_3}\: \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{bmatrix}$

thus $P_{C_1\rightarrow B_1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, and similarly $P_{B_1\rightarrow C_1} = (P_{C_1\rightarrow B_1})^{-1}$.

If you don't believe me:

solving for $\vec{u_1}=\frac{1}{2}(\vec{w_1}+\vec{w_3}),\vec{u_2}=\frac{1}{2}(\vec{w_3}-\vec{w_1}),\vec{u_3}=\frac{1}{2}(\vec{w_3}-\vec{w_1}-2\vec{w_2})$ then

$c_1\vec{u_1}+c_2\vec{u_2}+c_3\vec{u_3} = \left(\frac{c_1 - c_2 - c_3}{2}\right)\vec{w_1} +(-c_3)\vec{w_2}+\left(\frac{c_1+c_2+c_3}{2}\right)\vec{w_3}$ and

$\begin{bmatrix} \vec{u_1}\; \big|\; \vec{u_2}\;\big|\;  \vec{u_3}\: \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \vec{w_1}\; \big|\; \vec{w_2}\;\big|\;  \vec{w_3}\: \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \frac{c_1 - c_2 - c_3}{2} \\ -c_3 \\ \frac{c_1+c_2+c_3}{2} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \vec{w_1}\; \big|\; \vec{w_2}\;\big|\;  \vec{w_3}\: \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3 \end{bmatrix}$

where $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

*P.S.* I may or may not of mixed up the meanings of $P_{B_1\rightarrow C_1}$ and
$P_{C_1\rightarrow B_1}$